# Passing derived class around via base class property on controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, inheritance, asp.net-mvc-4, polymorphism

I'm building a wizard-style multi-step process in an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. I'm using TempData to hang on to the info from earlier steps, because the wizard isn't strictly linear - the user's choices on the first page actually result in them seeing one of three options for the third page. I'm achieving this by using their choice to assign one of three derived classes to a base-class property on the viewmodel for that third page. The page itself then uses a custom model binder to allow me to use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.BaseContainer)` and have it display the correct template for the user to fill in. My problem is that when the third page POSTs back, the controller method is of course expecting a base-class object, which means that when I save it in TempData, it only saves the base class properties.

I could do a series of checks along the lines of `if (viewModel.BaseContainer is DerivedClass1)`, but that seems like a hack. The whole point of the abstraction in using the base class is that the controller doesn't need to know which one it is at this point. Is there a more elegant way to save the object without losing the properties of the derived class?

Comment: Do you have some code to aid your description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tackled the same problem several months ago. We solved it using a smaller view model for each step in the wizard and then, on successful validation, we copied the values into a big view model (containing properties for everything in the wizard).  We then stored this big view model in `TempData` and progressed to the next step.

If you're adding new properties when deriving from your base class, then you're extending its interface, you could make extra interfaces for the new properties in each derived class, but this doesn't sound like a simple solution.

Comment: I'm doing something similar. Each step in the process has its own viewmodel, and there's an object which describes the entire request that the wizard is constructing. After each step, the contrller retrieves that model from TempData, extracts the required bits from the POST and adds them to the object, and then puts it back in TempData. My problem is that in this step, the required bits can only be accessed by their base class. I can add them to the object no problem (it has the same base-class property) but they don't seem to save their unique properties - just the base class ones.

Comment: Yep we had a similar problem, in the end we settled for using the automatic model binding through each step, translating the values into the big view model and then saving off the big view model at the end manually.  I'm not sure you can use a model binder based on the base class and retrieve the additional properties on any derived classes without using some sort of reflection (and it it could be done it might look messy).  I'm not model binder expert, so it'll be interesting to see if someone has more info.